# Does Ati Rudra Maha Yajna and Ekadash Rudram yield similar benefits?

Tags: vedas

I have heard **Ati Rudra Maha Yajna** and **Ekadash Rudram** yield similar benefits for the world i.e **samatha lokah sukino bhavanthu** is this correct?

Please clarify.
Thanks